# mailpit / kubernetes: SMTP sendmail cannot connect - telnet works fine

Tags: smtp, kubernetes, sendmail

kuberntes setup:

mailpit service + deployment
(ingress works, I can connect to the UI)

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: desideria-crm-mailpit
  namespace: desideria-crm
  labels:
    app: desideria-crm-mailpit
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8025
      name: http-sv
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 1025
      name: smtp-sv-tcp
      targetPort: smtp-tcp
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: desideria-crm-mailpit
  clusterIP: None

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: desideria-crm-mailpit
  namespace: desideria-crm
  labels:
    app: desideria-crm-mailpit
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: desideria-crm-mailpit
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: desideria-crm-mailpit
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: axllent/mailpit:v1.9.8
          name: desideria-crm-mailpit
          env:
            - name: MP_VERBOSE
              value: "true"         
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8025
              name: http
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 1025
              name: smtp-tcp
              protocol: TCP
```

Created a file email.txt on the pod:

```
From: sender@example.com
To: recipient@example.com
Subject: Email Subject

This is the body of the email.
It can contain multiple lines of text.
```

Then from the shell on the mailpit pod:

**TEST #1 against localhost from mailpit pod**

`sendmail -v -w 5 -t -oLogLevel=1 -S localhost:1025 < email.txt`

Result is ok, the mail shows up in the mailpit UI

```
sendmail: recv:'220 desideria-crm-mailpit-7cfbdb55d7-krdcw Mailpit ESMTP Service ready'
sendmail: send:'EHLO desideria-crm-mailpit-7cfbdb55d7-krdcw'
sendmail: recv:'250-desideria-crm-mailpit-7cfbdb55d7-krdcw greets desideria-crm-mailpit-7cfbdb55d7-krdcw'
sendmail: recv:'250-SIZE 0'
sendmail: recv:'250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES'
sendmail: send:'MAIL FROM:<root@desideria-crm-mailpit-7cfbdb55d7-krdcw>'
sendmail: recv:'250 2.1.0 Ok'
sendmail: send:'RCPT TO:<recipient@example.com>'
sendmail: recv:'250 2.1.5 Ok'
sendmail: send:'DATA'
sendmail: recv:'354 Start mail input; end with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>'
sendmail: send:'From: sender@example.com'
sendmail: send:'To: recipient@example.com'
sendmail: send:'Subject: Email Subject'
sendmail: send:''
sendmail: send:'This is the body of the email.'
sendmail: send:'It can contain multiple lines of text.'
sendmail: send:'.'
sendmail: recv:'250 2.0.0 Ok: queued'
sendmail: send:'QUIT'
sendmail: recv:'221 2.0.0 desideria-crm-mailpit-7cfbdb55d7-krdcw Mailpit ESMTP Service closing transmission channel'
```

**TEST #2 desideria-crm-mailpit (this time from another pod within the same kubernetes namespace)**

`sendmail -v -w 5 -t -oLogLevel=1 -S desideria-crm-mailpit:1025 < email.txt`

Timeout after 5 seconds, higher timeout also does not work.

```
Alarm clock
```

**TEST #3 desideria-crm-mailpit (using a java app from another pod within same namespace)**

side notes:

- this works when testing on local pc against a localhost running mailpit docker container / no kubernetes)
- the app also works with a real smtp server authentication etc...

```
DEBUG: Jakarta Mail version 2.1.1
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/var/lib/jar/desideriacare-crm-api.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/var/lib/jar/desideriacare-crm-api.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imap=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtp=jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], pop3=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], imaps=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], smtps=jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3s=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/var/lib/jar/desideriacare-crm-api.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar!/META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/var/lib/jar/desideriacare-crm-api.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar!/META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "desideria-crm-mailpit", port 1025, isSSL false
DEBUG SMTP: exception reading response, THROW: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:280)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:306)
..... shortened
```

**TEST #4 desideria-crm-mailpit (using telnet from SAME pod as TEST #2)**

`telnet desideria-crm-mailpit 1025`

Result works - but why?

```
Connected to desideria-crm-mailpit
EHLO testingstuff         
220 desideria-crm-mailpit-7cfbdb55d7-krdcw Mailpit ESMTP Service ready
250-desideria-crm-mailpit-7cfbdb55d7-krdcw greets testingstuff
250-SIZE 0
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
MAIL FROM:<root@testingstuff.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<recipient@example.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
354 Start mail input; end with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
From: sender@example.com
To: recipient@example.com
Subject: Email Subject

r1
r2
last row
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued
```

**Summary**

- sendmail from mailpit pod it self works
- sendmail from **testpod A** does not work
- java app from testpod B does not work
- telnet from **testpod A** does work !!
- ping `desideria-crm-mailpit` / IP works from ANY pod.
- nslookup retrieves correct pod's IP
- Also tried mailhog pod instead of mailpit. Same result.

What are sendmail/java app maybe doing different compared to telnet?

Using the pods/service IP instead of the service name `desideria-crm-mailpit` i get the same results.

I am really confused since database services like mariadb/mongodb which are setup in the same manner besides the ports can be reached from the java app and work perfectly fine.

Comment: Make sure that there are no network policies or firewall rules that might be blocking communication to the service.
It appears that there might be an issue related to DNS resolution or firewall configuration.

Comment: No network policies enabled, no firewall enabled. I am currently checking if istio (default installation, no adjustments) might be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that istio causes the issue. Once sidecars are no longer injected. Everything works as expected.

With istio sidecar the following adjustment had to be done in my case:

Add to Service smtp port:

```
appProtocol: tcp
```

or

```
appProtocol: tls
```

Final service manifest

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: desideria-crm-mailpit
  namespace: desideria-crm
  labels:
    app: desideria-crm-mailpit
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8025
      name: http-sv
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 1025
      name: smtp-sv-tcp
      targetPort: smtp-tcp
      protocol: TCP
      appProtocol: tcp # IMPORTANT for mailpit SMTP
  selector:
    app: desideria-crm-mailpit
  clusterIP: None
```